# If $1/m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^p,$ then is $1/(1+m)$ also a Fourier multiplier?

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

I am studying the concept of Fourier multipliers in $L^p$ and I have a doubt.
Suppose $1/m$ is a Fourier multiplier in $L^p$ (with $1<p<\infty$). From what I can see, $1/(1+m)$ must also be a Fourier multiplier, but I don't see how to prove it in a simple way. (I don't think I should do the hard calculation because it is only adding $1$.) Is there any general result to conclude that the function $1/(1+m)$ is also a multiplier? Thanks.

pd: To avoid technical steps or singularities, suppose that $1/m(x)$ and $1+m(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: If $m=-1$ surely not ...

Comment: But, if $1+m\neq 0$

Comment: Even if you assume $1+m\neq 0 $ you will still have a problem if $1+m$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ so you need some assumption.

Comment: That's why I asked the question. I know that if $1/m(x)$ is a multiplier, then so is $1/m(x+1)$ (a translation still holds the multiplier property. Similar to this, is there a property that allows us to conclude that $1/(1+m(x))$ is it too?